# Convert Sass String (not SCSS) to CSS String

Tags: css, node.js, sass, node-sass

I need to compile **SASS** and **SCSS** Strings to **CSS** Strings for a project. Therefore I´m using the node package node-sass. Converting SCSS works fine, but SASS doesn't.

Example code for SASS:

```
'use strict';

var sass = require('node-sass');

var dataTemp = 'body{background:blue; a{color:black;}}';

var output = sass.renderSync({
  data: dataTemp
});

console.log(output.css.toString());
```

The problem comes, when I try to convert something like this, which should be valid .sass syntax

```
'use strict';

var sass = require('node-sass');

var dataTemp = '.red\n color: red';

var output = sass.renderSync({
  data: dataTemp
});

console.log(output.css.toString());
```

Console output:

```
Error: Invalid CSS after ".": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was ".red color: red "
```

So obviously node-sass can't compile .sass code that way. The syntax of node-sass is:

```
var result = sass.renderSync({
  data: scss_content
  [, options..]
});
```

Inside the object you can define options and even functions. Maybe is there a way to compile the data in such a function?

Any other solutions or recommendations for other packages?

Comment: You haven't told us why this doesn't work? You also have a typo in `outpu.css`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well by adding an option named 'indentedSyntax' and setting it to 'true', node-sass can compile .sass code as well. Sorry, should have read the documentation more precisely. Thanks for helping!

```
'use strict';

var sass = require('node-sass');

var dataTemp = '.red\n color: red';

var output = sass.renderSync({
  data: dataTemp,
  indentedSyntax: true,
  outputStyle : 'compressed'
});

console.log(output.css.toString());
```

Log: ".red{color:red}"

Answer (score 2):

Your SCSS is invalid - you need to provide the `{}` around your properties:

```
'use strict';

var sass = require('node-sass');

var dataTemp = '.red {color: red}';

var output = sass.renderSync({
  data: dataTemp
});

console.log(output.css.toString());
```

You can validate your SASS/SCSS using an online tool such as [SassMeister](http://www.sassmeister.com/)

Comment: Right, the normal SCSS Syntax works fine, but the SASS Syntax, which I need aswell doesn't. Had a typo there, but '.red\n color: red' should be vaild .sass Syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct. See the update to my post above - using the validator, your original value is invalid, but the value I have suggested is valid.

Comment: Unfortunately I´m not that familiar with  SASS/SCSS, but I think I need the Syntax discribed in [link](http://sass-lang.com/guide), where you can witch between SCSS and SASS Syntax. Therefore I thought, that ".red\n color: red" should be valid?